# Navigation bar : Navigate between different screens

Tags: android

is there a good tutorial for navigation in android like UINavigation in iOS: To navigate to some screen,then pressing back button to come back to the caller screen i.e. stacking,keep on pushing to new screens and then pressing back to pop current screen and go to caller screen.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at ActionBar ?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

For advanced navigation, also look at SlidingMenu

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: yeah this doc works, but sample code given does not run, a lot of errors there

Comment: You can post a separate question for that. I will look.